Flutter Text changes height when emoji included
I'm having a huge struggle with the Flutter Text component. Whenever we have a text with an emoji, the line height/baseline doesn't match the one from Figma or when the text is without an emoji. Because of this, all the designs are really hard to tweak, and stuff just looks bad.
Problem 1:


First box - Figma
Second box - text on iOS 17.5, with no emoji, baseline matches
Third box - same button but with an emoji inside, it is offset and misaligned. Of course, no parameters like text weight, font size, or height change. We are using Nunito font.

Text(
  'Play ', // Only emoji changes
  style: context.textTheme.titleLarge?.copyWith(
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
    fontFamily: FontFamily.nunito,
  ),
),

Problem 2:

As you can see, the middle line is slightly offset whenever there is an emoji inside.
Has anyone had the same problem?

Try to use RichText widget, which allows you to customize the style of individual text spans within the widget.

You can like below.
    const Text(
    'You have pushed the button this many times ✈️You have pushed the button this many times ✈️You have pushed the button this many times',
     style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)
    ),

Simply use TextStyle instead of context.textTheme.titleLarge?.copyWith


What I'm using is a TextStyle, I just reference the default one from the context. It doesn't matter how you create it.
